# Java Memcached not replicating entries across instances

Tags: java, memcached, load-balancing

I am using xmemcached-1.3.5 jar version of MemCache server.

Now, I have two instances of this server on different machine.  I am 
using xmemcached-1.3.5 jar  to make entry in memcache-server through my 
java application.

When both servers are up, the entry is made on only one of the MemCache instances.

Is there any configuration that needs to be made to get the entries duplicated onto both instances?

Comment: Please tag more carefully. "clustering" is an alias for [tag:cluster-analysis], you probably meant [tag:load-balancing] instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memcached does not provide replication. You will need to investigate repcached if you want your cached data replicated.